# JS auto scroll looping

Tags: javascript

I'm not familiar with js. I found this code. I need a help to improve this to loop the scrolling. Now it scroll down for once. What I need is when the list gets to end, need to start with the top of the list again itself. Please help. Thank you.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/EshanRajapakshe/43dhju4m/

Ex:

- List content 1
- List content 2
- List content 3
- List content 4
- List content 5
- List content 1
- List content 2
- List content 3

Code:

```
quadroDeAvisos = document.getElementById("quadroDeAvisos")
lineUp = document.getElementById("lineUp")
avisos = lineUp.getElementsByClassName("avisos")

var count = 0;
var limite = avisos.length -1;
var myVar=setInterval(function(){atualiza()},2000);

function atualiza() {
    if(count == limite)
    count = 0;
  lineUp.style.marginTop = 65*count*(-1)+"px"
  count++
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As per your logic I have updated your code please check

```js
quadroDeAvisos = document.getElementById("quadroDeAvisos")
lineUp = document.getElementById("lineUp")
avisos = lineUp.getElementsByClassName("avisos")

var count = 0;
var myVar=setInterval(function(){atualiza()},2000);

function atualiza() {
  lineUp.style.marginTop = 65*count*(-1)+"px"
  count++
  if(count == 5)
    count = 0
}
```

```css
.quadroDeAvisos{
  width: 134px;
  height: 125px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#quadroDeAvisos .avisos {
  background-color: #ee9d20;
  border-color: #ba7c18;
}

.avisos {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  height: 50px;
  width: 132px;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.lineUp{
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quadroDeAvisos" id="quadroDeAvisos">
<div class="lineUp" id="lineUp">
<div class="avisos">
  <p>List content 1</p>
<p>Sub content</p> 
</div>
<div class="avisos">
  <p>List content 2</p>
<p>Sub content</p> 
</div>
<div class="avisos">
  <p>List content 3</p>
<p>Sub content</p> 
</div>
<div class="avisos">
  <p>List content 4</p>
<p>Sub content</p> 
</div>
<div class="avisos">
  <p>List content 5</p>
<p>Sub content</p> 
</div>

</div></div></div>
```

Comment: comments in code would add to the perfection :)
PS : just a comment

Comment: Thank you for the help. But this is not how I exactly wanted sir. Please see the example. When the list ends, it needs to start from the top smoothly again just after the bottom of the list continually. In this code, end of the code it jumps to the first. that's not how I meant.

Comment: I'm truly sorry for your inconvenience about the code comments. I didn't wrote that code sir. I found it on the internet. And I don't know JS. I'm a student.

Answer (score 0):

Check I updated your logic with your requirment. Hope it helps

```js
function autoScrollDown(){
    $(".inner").css({top:-$(".lineUp").outerHeight()}) // jump back
               .animate({top:0},10000,"linear", autoScrollDown); // and animate
}
function autoScrollUp(){
    $(".inner").css({top:0}) // jump back
               .animate({top:-$(".lineUp").outerHeight()},10000,"linear", autoScrollUp); // and animate
}
// fix hight of lineUp:
$('.lineUp').css({maxHeight: $('.inner').height()});
// duplicate content of inner:
$('.inner').html($('.inner').html() + $('.inner').html());
autoScrollUp();
```

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.inner{
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
}
.lineUp{
    overflow:hidden;
}
.avisos {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  height: 50px;
  width: 132px;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ee9d20;
  border-color: #ba7c18;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="lineUp">
    <div class="inner" id="lineUp">
        <h3 class="avisos">List content 1<p> Sub content </p></h3>
        <h3 class="avisos">List content 2<p> Sub content </p></h3> 
        <h3 class="avisos">List content 3<p> Sub content </p></h3> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The list works how I expected. But the each content need to be stop maybe a second to see and read the content easily and clearly. Just like the previous code. Hold the list content for a second and move on. I think you got that. Thank you.